# Asking for a linux command to put some scattered files together

Tags: linux, macos, shell, command

In my Mac OS file system, I have some  files organized in a Root_Folder like this:

```
Root_Folder/
      /Sub_Folder1
              file1
      /Sub_Folder2
              file2
       ....
      /Sub_FolderN
              fileN
```

Now I want to put all these file1...fileN into another folder, without those Sub_Folders. Is there  a magic linux command that can achieve this?

For info, the real names of the sub_folders many be very different one from the other, so using "cp  Root_Folder/Sub_Folder*/* Another_Folder" should not work". Also, the real names of file_i above differ from one the other as well, thus we do not need to worry about name conflict when copying them to the same place.

Comment: Rather puzzling that you reference MacOS FS but tag linux and show Windows style slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find RootFolder -type f -print | xargs -I file echo mv file newdir/
```

will find all the files under `RootFolder` and move them into `newdir`.  If you want to keep the original files, replace `mv` with `cp`.

Answer (score 2):

The following command should do the trick:

```
cp Root_Folder/*/* Another_Folder
```

However, you need to make sure that file names are unique because otherwise `file1` from `Sub_Folder2` would overwrite `file1` from `Sub_Folder1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` utility:

```
find Root_Folder -type f -exec mv {} Another_Folder \;
```

which find all files (not directories) and execute command:

```
mv $CURRENT_FILE Another_Folder
```